# Broken img only on Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome

So in [here](http://siodental.com) (on the bottom of the page) you can see (only if using chrome) a broken image at the bottom left.

It turns out that accessing it directly works. The chrome console also gives a 404 error for the image.

I'm using a php file to serve that image. I get the show arg and use readfile to serve that image. (the code works, as seen in other browsers or accessing it directly)

I don't know what's the deal with chrome.

Any help would be appreciated!

I'm using wordpress as a base, and I'm using the following php file to filter what users ids are able to see certain images.

Sorry if the code is messy. I'm still learning!

```
<?php

define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-blog-header.php');

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$current_user_id = $current_user->ID;

//save idlength to compare

$idLength=strlen($current_user_id);

//check for arg
if (isset($_GET['show'])) {

    $img="../Subidas_cliente/{$_GET['show']}";

    //check whether file exists
    if (file_exists($img)){

        //admin ids always get image 
        if($current_user_id==2||$current_user_id==10||$current_user_id==12||$current_user_id==13){
            readfile($img);
        }

        else{

            //compare ids from image and requester
            $tmp=substr($img,0,$idLength);
            $r=strcmp($tmp, $current_user_id);


            if ($r==0){

                $mime_type = mime_content_type($img);
                header('Content-Type: '.$mime_type);

                //readfile if ids are equal
                readfile($img);

            //exit if different (return image for testing purposes)
            }else{
                header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
                readfile('../Subidas_cliente/default.jpg');
            }
        }

    }else {
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        readfile('../Subidas_cliente/default.jpg');
    }
}else{
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    readfile('../Subidas_cliente/default.jpg');
}

?>
```

Comment: I can see the broken image on Firefox too. - http://siodental.com/img.php?show=2_1330_A1.jpg - `GET /img.php?show=2_1330_A1.jpg HTTP/1.1`- response: `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`

Comment: The link is broken : http://siodental.com/img.php?show=2_1330_A1.jpg. Not depending of the browser.

Comment: Post the php code that's generating the image so we can help you further.

Comment: added the php file above

Comment: I'll look into it. I dont think so though. Thank you for the edit!!

Comment: @bbbb Is there anything showing up in your PHP error logs?

Comment: You made me discover the error_log! Thank you :)

Comment: I get an unexepected else on line 35 (meaning last else) I don't see the problem...

Comment: The last `else` is not line 35. I count 50 lines in that file. Look at the error carefully and make sure you are looking in the correct file and the correct line number. If you don't have one, get a text editor with line numbers.

Comment: I added comments to simplify understanding my file only in the one here. That's why lines are different! EDIT: Nevermind, last error was an hour ago. I was confused with UTC timezone. PHP doesn't give any errors.

Comment: @bbbb I think I got blocked by your site. It stopped loading for me after I tried to "hack" your image thing by putting in `/etc/passwd` as the image file. Anyway, `unexpected else` is because the `else` is not following an `if` or `ifelse` block.

Comment: @bbbb I connected to a proxy and your server appears to be doing something really strange, likely something to do with rewrites. If I go to http://siodental.com/img.php?show=2_1330_A1.jpg directly (in chrome) it displays the image, however it returns a 404 status code. Something that is not in the PHP code you pasted above is causing `img.php` to return a 404 status code, which is why it isn't being displayed in the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out loading wordpress functions like that is troublesome (and buggy). I ended up transfering the ID through a session (session_start and $_SESSION['']) variable and it solved everything.